# How to use v-bind to add "dynamic" class to button

Tags: class, vue.js

so i have a getter (neither getter or paged component have all desired status values) im thinking of somehow using the getter for this without success

```
getStatusValues: (state) => {
    return [
      { id: 0, name: i18n.t('OK') },
      { id: 1, name: i18n.t('Running') },
      { id: 2, name: i18n.t('Error') }
    ]
  },
```

and i want to bind a class to a button in this self paged component

```
<div class="objs">
        <div
          v-for="obj in objPage"
          :key="obj.id"
          class="obj"
        >
          <button
            :class="{class1:obj.status === 'OK', class2: obj.status === 'NotRunning', class3: obj.status === 'Running', Err: obj.status === 'Error'}"
            @click="Dialog(obj)"
          >
            {{ obj.id }}
          </button>
        </div>

        <div
          v-for="i in (objPage.length < 9) ? 9 - objPage.length : 0"
          :key="i"
          class="empty"
        />
      </div>
```

is there a way i could perhaps make all the status values dynamically be the class names and only have to do one check for `{classname:obj.status === "classname"}` cause the way i have went about it is not the best and i want to find a diffrent one

Comment: not saying status will be a string i can always filter for the name using the getter

Comment: I would say just use `obj.status` and if it's not always a string, use a computed or getter to return one based on `status`

Comment: you mean :class="obj.status"?

Comment: oh that migth work

Comment: So none posted an answer so ill do it i in the end i went with a diffrent way cause my status's will not be strings all the time meaning i can't have classes for every status that way

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
:class="obj.status"
```